# What is the strftime config for an amazon athena timestamp

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-athena, presto

In python 3, I'd do something like this:

`"{0:Y-M-d H:m:?.???}".format(datetime.datetime.now())`

However, having searched a bit, it would be nice to have a canonical answer somewhere.

Comment: You linked to documentation for Redshift. Presto (and so Athena) does not support sub-milliseconds precision in timestamp values.

Comment: man, can't believe I didn't see that. good catch. I'm just looking for the basic timestamp format, subsecond isn't necessary

Comment: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/language/types.html#timestamp has this example: `TIMESTAMP '2001-08-22 03:04:05.321'`, i think it's self-explanatory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late to the game and I like your answer of just using total seconds but here's how I got athena (using awswrangler) to work with datetime & strftime

`query_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

`query_statement = f"SELECT * FROM table where datetime_col > timestamp '{query_date}'"`

my datetime_col has 3 milli seconds but it was not necessary in my query

Comment: i'm just gonna have to trust you this worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, i chose not to use a timestamp but instead of treat it as an integer and store seconds since epoch. This is effects the same outcome with much less drama. Athena has all the functions one needs to convert these ints into dates for date math. So it is just easier.